# Emacs doesn't use macOS's /etc/launchd.conf env variables

Tags: osx, java, environment

Emacs doesn't use macOS's /etc/launchd.conf env variables. I have the following there:

```
function addToPATH {
    case ":$PATH:" in
        *":$1:"*) :;; # already there
        *) PATH="$1:$PATH";; # or PATH="$PATH:$1"
    esac
}

export JAVA_HOME8=`/usr/libexec/java_home --version 1.8`
export JAVA_HOME9=`/usr/libexec/java_home --version 9`
export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME8
addToPATH $JAVA_HOME
```

But when I use `getenv` in Emacs to see my JAVA_HOME, it's unset. Setting it using `setenv` in my init file solves my issue, but this is an ugly workaround.

PS: I also set this variable in `.zshenv`, which I source in `.bashrc`, which I source in `.bash_profile`. So I am really confused that Emacs is not picking this up.

Comment: Many people with OSX use this library to set the path and exec-path: https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell  I personally prefer to set those variables at the time a process is launched or on a buffer-local basis, but that requires advanced Emacs tinkering with the functions ...  To set other environmental variables, you may wish to have a look at the *function* `setenv-internal` and set the *variable* `process-environment`.